# How to update a fork on github

Tags: git, github

I forked a repo on github and changed a couple of things.
The original repo has committed a couple of things.
How can I update my fork without re-forking and undoing all my changes?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From your terminal in your local project folder...(and provided you have [configured the remote for your fork](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-remote-for-a-fork/))

```
git fetch upstream
git checkout master
git merge upstream/master
```

(See the github [Syncing a fork docs](https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/) for more info)